# How to generate executable scripts using spring boot maven plugin

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

Using spring boot maven plugin we are able to generate executable jars. And we can execute the jar using java -jar ...

In spring boot there is another option for [installation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html) . This generates the jar which can be added in init.d.

But is it possible to generate a sh|cmd file which can be used to start|stop|restart spring boot applications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The executable true  flag to create a 'fully executable’ jar actually pre-pends a shell script into the beginning of the jar.

It works outside init.d too. Try this:

```
./myapp.jar start
```